# How to ignore a split pattern while the string is to be split by that character

Tags: regex, perl

First, sorry for my English and the confusing description in the title.

My problem here is I have multiple lines of natural phrases, I want to count the words contained in it. I have came up with the following regex in Perl:

```
my @words = split /[ :,.;\s\/\t!"\n]+/, $_;
```

It works fine except that when encounter with a word like 'U.S.A' it breaks the word into U,S and A, which is undesired. What can I do to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output for `U.S.A`?

Comment: it should remain like U.S.A without any changes

Comment: How about a domain name like "www.google.com"? Should this be split as "www", "google", "com" or not?

Comment: You don't want to split single alphabet word. Right?

Comment: no, I don't want to split it.

Comment: no, I don't want to split it.

Comment: How about U.States.Of.A? I'm trying to understand the kinds of scenarios that you may encounter. Are there any assumptions about the input that you can make?

Comment: I believe if they are consecutive and split by '.', I should treat it as a whole word.

Comment: In that case, why're you even considering "." as a split character? Since "U.S.A" and "U.States.Of.A" should be considered as a single word, can't you just remove "." from the list of separators?

Comment: No, I have to keep it as a whole word. Because that is also the way treated by some libraries.

Comment: Is it safe to say that you only want to split based on "." if it serves as the end of a sentence? For example, "My name is Jack." will result in "My, name, is, Jack". But "I live in the U.S.A." will result in "I, live, in, the, U.S.A"

Comment: I think so. I want to have a pattern to match this, in case I may encounter other similar scenarios like A:B:C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split based off spaces, but then remove any non-word characters from the beginning and end of the "words".  That way `U.S.A.` would end up as `U.S.A`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $_ = 'hello world, U.S.A., and other places.';

my @words = map { s/^\W+|\W+$//g; $_ } split /\s+/, $_;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@words;
```

Outputs

```
["hello", "world", "U.S.A", "and", "other", "places"]
```

Comment: thank you Miller, it seems to work, except there should be a '/' before the global matcher. BTW, what will be matched by \w, it seems that words like I'm or 'U.S.A' will be matched as a whole word, what is the rule of it?

Comment: \W is a non word character.  Roughly speaking it's [^_a-zA-Z0-9].  A detailed description can be found at [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). Just search for "Character Classes and other Special Escapes"